# How does the Homogenous clip space look like after Projection matrix

Tags: opengl, 3d, glm-math

I am confuse how the Clip space (which is the space after projection matrix multiplication) looks like?
I am ready tutorial (and maybe misunderstanding it) and it says the values are in the -1 and 1 range, but isnt that value/range after the perspective divide?
There is also a tutorial in learnopengl.com that says the projection matrix transform the coordinate from view space to NDC, but im pretty sure its not correct as NDC is after the perspective divide (which is a fixed function in the pipeline).

So how does the Homegeneous clip space (space after Projection matrix) looks like? it is not in the range of -1 to 1 isnt it or is it?

Please enlighten me. Thank you in advance

Comment: It is NDS is a unique cube, with the left bottom near (-1, -1, -1) and right top far (1, 1, 1)

Comment: sorry i dont understand your answer :) so youre saying that after the projection matrix transform the result is in NDC before the divide by w happened?

Comment: No. After the transformation with the projection matrix, the coordinates are in clip space. In clip space the geometry is clipped -w < x, y, z < w. Clip space coordinates are Homogeneous coordinates. After the perspective divide the coordinates are in NDS. NDS coordinates are Cartesian. See [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).

Comment: Rabbid76 - That's explicitly not what the question is asking: That NDS cube is the result *after the perspective divide*; the question is what does the space look like before. Ie, what does *z* map to; your comment answers what w/z maps to.

Answer (score 0):

After the transformation with the projection matrix, the coordinates are in clip space. In clip space the geometry is clipped (*-w < x, y, z < w*). Clip space coordinates are [Homogeneous coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates). After the [Perspective divide](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Post-Processing#Perspective_divide) the coordinates are in Normalized device space. NDS coordinates are [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system). See [Rendering Pipeline Overview](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Rendering_Pipeline_Overview).